# Microsoft Speech Platform - how to update rules at runtime

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-platform

I am using the System.Speech to build a C# application with voice recognition capabilities.

I read this post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127913.aspx that mentions how to update rules dynamically at runtime.

I wonder how I can do the same trick with the C# System.Speech API.
Do you have any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

System.Speech is a bit different from the SAPI described under this link, however, it's even easier to construct grammars in runtime, you can use [GrammarBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for that. You can add any structure of choices and rules to construct the language you need to recognize.

Once you updated the grammar you can load the grammar into recognizer recognizer with [LoadGrammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.loadgrammar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I played a little bit with the GrammarBuilder. The problem is that I would like to update rules of a static grammar file in runtime. The grammar is not created from GrammarBuilder but loaded from an XML file. So, I search for updating the rule of a loaded grammar file.

Do you think that it would be best to use the SAPI API (that we could install with the Win 7 dev kit from what I undersand...)?

Comment: You can also load grammar XML files in GrammarBuilder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms576568.aspx. Overall, System.Speech is pretty flexible API and has a lot of capabilities. If you are working in C#, there is no need to look for SAPI.

Comment: The problem is that i am not able to  to update a rule after having loading the grammar file. I found somme example with SAPI but not with system.speech. do you have any example?

Comment: I finally useed the SAPI 5.4 API and the SpeechLib library and it works.

Comment: Hi Itu, I'm confronting the same problem and I'm wondering if you still had that code lying around, maybe you could post a sample for others as the correct solution?